# Separate Excel rows into individual sheets and retain header

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use VBA in Excel to separate rows into separate sheets and retain headers.  Below is what I have so far. It works except I get the header row, then the individual row I want to move to the sheet is there BUT it's there three times instead of one.  I am basically going by trial and error and I am stumped. Help please!  I have no experience with this:

```
Sub DispatchTimeSeriesToSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Scoring")
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' stop processing if we don't have any data
If LastRow < 2 Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
SortScoring LastRow, ws
CopyDataToSheets LastRow, ws
ws.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub SortScoring(LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet)
ws.Range("A4:W" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=ws.Range("A4"), Key2:=ws.Range("W4")
End Sub

Sub CopyDataToSheets(LastRow As Long, src As Worksheet)
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim Series As String
Dim SeriesStart As Long
Dim SeriesLast As Long

Set rng = Range("A4:A" & LastRow)
SeriesStart = 2
Series = Range("A" & SeriesStart).Value
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value <> Series Then
        SeriesLast = cell.Row - 1
        CopySeriesToNewSheet src, SeriesStart, SeriesLast, Series
        Series = cell.Value
        SeriesStart = cell.Row
    End If
Next
' copy the last series
SeriesLast = LastRow
CopySeriesToNewSheet src, SeriesStart, SeriesLast, Series

End Sub

Sub CopySeriesToNewSheet(src As Worksheet, Start As Long, Last As Long, _
                                                    name As String)
Dim tgt As Worksheet

If (SheetExists(name)) Then
    MsgBox "Sheet " & name & " already exists. " _
    & "Please delete or move existing sheets before" _
    & " copying data from the Scoring.", vbCritical, _
    "Time Series Parser"
    End
End If

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).name = name
Set tgt = Sheets(name)

' copy header row from src to tgt
tgt.Range("A1:W1").Value = src.Range("A1:W1").Value

' copy data from src to tgt
tgt.Range("A4:W" & Last - Start + 2).Value = _
    src.Range("A" & Start & ":W" & Last).Value
End Sub

Function SheetExists(name As String) As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet

SheetExists = True
On Error Resume Next
Set ws = Sheets(name)
If ws Is Nothing Then
   SheetExists = False
End If
End Function
```

Comment: To make sure I understand, you have a series of values in column a with duplicates like  `apples,apples,apples,bananas,bananas, oranges` and you want to move those records to a sheet with that name (3 records to apples, 2 to bananas and 1 to oranges) and keep the headers from the source sheet?

Comment: Part of your problem is likely coming from `tgt.Range("A4:W" & Last - Start + 2).Value = _
    src.Range("A" & Start & ":W" & Last).Value` line since you are putting the header in row 1 and then pasting the data starting in row 4..I've posted an answer below that should give you an idea of how to deal with this

Comment: I have a spreadsheet that has 3 header rows, then one row per person with scores across the row. I want to get the headers plus each student's row into a separate sheet.  So sheet 1would be rows 1-3 as header, row 4 - Sam's info, sheet 2 would be rows 1-3 as header with row 4 including George's info, etc. I have absolutely no experience with writing VBA in Exce. I suppose that's obvious:)

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you are looking for

```
Const HeaderRow = 3
Sub MoveRecordsByValues()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim dws As Worksheet
Dim SheetName As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In Sheets
If ws.name <> "Scoring" Then ws.Delete
Next ws
Set ws = Sheets("Scoring")
StartRow = HeaderRow + 1
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For RowCounter = StartRow To LastRow
    SheetName = ws.Cells(RowCounter, 1)
    If Not SheetExists(SheetName) Then SetUpSheet SheetName, ws, HeaderRow
    Set dws = Worksheets(SheetName)
    DestLastRow = dws.Range("A" & dws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws.Rows(RowCounter).Copy dws.Cells(DestLastRow, 1)
Next RowCounter
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Function SheetExists(name As String) As Boolean
    SheetExists = True
    On Error GoTo errorhandler
    Sheets(name).Activate
    Exit Function
errorhandler:
    SheetExists = False
End Function

Sub SetUpSheet(name, SourceSheet, HeaderRow)
    Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
    Set DestSheet = Sheets.Add
    DestSheet.name = name
    SourceSheet.Rows(1).Copy DestSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    SourceSheet.Rows(2).Copy DestSheet.Cells(2, 1)
    SourceSheet.Rows(3).Copy DestSheet.Cells(3, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks -- it got close! But now I get no header row text and then two rows of data that are different people.  The original spreadsheet has 3 header rows, then one row per person with a list of course scores. I'd like to retain the three header rows (with the formatting if that's possible) and then one student row per worksheet.  I really appreciate the help. I am just trying to figure this out based on reading what you all have posted here.  Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer to bring all three header rows over, try it now

Comment: Oh my gosh! You are my hero! People in my office will think I am a genius:) I guess I'll have to be honest and tell them I got a huge assist from you. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub doitall()
Dim ows As Worksheet
Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim tLastRow As Long

Set ows = Sheets("Scoring")

With ows
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A4:A" & LastRow)
    For Each cel In rng
        If Not SheetExists(cel.Value) Then
            Set tws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
            tws.Name = cel.Value
            tws.Rows(1).Resize(3).Value = .Rows(1).Resize(3).Value
        Else
            Set tws = Sheets(cel.Value)
        End If
        tLastRow = tws.Range("A" & tws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        tws.Rows(tLastRow).Value = .Rows(cel.Row).Value
    Next
End With

End Sub
 Function SheetExists(SName As String, _
                     Optional ByVal WB As Workbook) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    If WB Is Nothing Then Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
    SheetExists = CBool(Len(WB.Sheets(SName).Name))
End Function
```