# Taking Values from Column 1, putting on seperate worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

Using VBA within Excel; I have names within Column 1 on my active sheet, I want to take them over to their own worksheet. So all cells with value of "Name1" goes to worksheet renamed to "Name1" and the same for all the names within the column. The number of names isn't set. I'm unsure how to procede on this as I'm new to the copying to new worksheets.

Comment: 1) Are there any discontinuities in the Name1 column? Or will looping until an empty cell is found always get all the records?
2) Do you need to create a new worksheet?

Comment: This question has been answered many many times on this site alone.  Here is [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569653/separate-excel-rows-into-individual-sheets-and-retain-header/33571637#33571637).  You will need to adjust it a little to do exactly what you want.  But start there try to fix and come back when you have specific problems modifying.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the range End property to select the relevant cells and copy their values to corresponding cells in the required target column in the worksheet Name1.

In the following I assume

1. You want to copy Names from row 2 down (e.g. because you have a header row)
2. You want to copy into the first column of a new worksheet named Name1, starting from row 2
3. The original worksheet from which you're copying is your [ActiveSheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx)

Just assign the following code to whatever button or event you like:

```
Sub CopyNames()

Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim NameSheet As Worksheet


' Prevent Excel screen from flickering as it copies
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Set the range of data you have to copy in column A, from row 2 to the last non-empty cell
Set TargetRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2", ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown))

' Add the worksheet and rename it
Set NameSheet = Worksheets.Add
NameSheet.Name = "Name1"

' Copy and paste to the new worksheet
TargetRange.Copy
NameSheet.Cells(2, 1).Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste

' Exit Copy mode
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```